# PHPMyAdmin Default login password

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have done a fresh installation of Fedora 14 and installed the phpMyAdmin module. When I run phpMyAdmin, it asks me for a username and password.

What is the default username and password for phpMyAdmin?

Comment: default database username: root and the password is empty...  so Username:root , Password:

Comment: Also try username: root and password: root if AllowNoPassword condition is set.

Comment: I just install PHPMyadmin And default username was diffren

Comment: I Just install PHPMyadmin   and default Username  was  phpmyadmin and password was asked during install ..
as well you cane use MySQL root user and password to login

Comment: I am using mamp and I've seen commonly it has a default of Username : "root" and Password : "root"

Answer (score 171):

Default is:

```
Username: root

Password: [null]
```

*The Password is set to 'password' in some versions.*

Comment: For newer version, this is the username password but would only work when @KarmicDice's solution of updating to AllowNoPassword is done

Comment: In Version 4.0.6 Default username is still : **root**
But default password is changed to : **password**

Comment: neither is working for me.

Comment: If you are using AMPPS, the pass is mysql

Comment: didn't work for version 4.4.11. neither root, not root:password, nor root:mysql

Comment: This solution works if `AllowNoPassword` is true in config. Doesn't work for me

Comment: By default password will be either [null] or root.

Answer (score 70):

I just installed Fedora 16 (yea, I know it's old and not supported but, I had the CD burnt :) )

Anyway, coming to the solution, this is what I was required to do:

```
su -
gedit /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

if not found... try phpmyadmin - all small caps.

```
gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Locate

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']
```

and set it to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Save it.

Comment: Awesome fix. Here is the file location for ver phpMyAdmin-4.0.5 phpMyAdmin-4.0.5/libraries/config.default.php

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It's set correctly, and it makes sense, but phpMyAdmin is always coming back to me with "Login without password is forbidden".

Comment: It's `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` instead of `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` (all lower case)

Comment: Corrected @becko . Thanks. Next time feel free to edit it yourself :)

Comment: For me the AllowNoPassword = TRUE; thing was already there, I just had to uncomment it.

Comment: It did not solve this issue even after changing it to TRUE. What can be other option to change the password of phpmyadmin

Comment: Change the password of phpmyadmin? AllowNoPassword is set to true when you use MySQL default installation which has no password.

Answer (score 59):

This is asking for your **MySQL** username and password.

You should enter these details, which will default to "root" and "" (i.e.: nothing) if you've not specified a password.

Comment: That it for me, there was a dialog asking login password, but it was just login/password for MySQL

Comment: This is the best answer, LOL on my intellegence
:D
+1 for your bang on answer
:)

Comment: This is true for the logon page, but not the setup page.

Comment: For security reasons it is password protected and only accessible when using 127.0.0.1 as the hostname

Answer (score 7):

If it was installed with plesk (not sure if it's just that, or on the phpmyadmin side: It changes the root user to admin.