# how do I retrieve PHPmyadmin's password? Cant log in to the host's phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am having problems to access the phpmyadmin installed on the hostserver. I have installed the phpmyadmin there and when i set the user as "root" and leave the password space blanked at `http://192.254.143.28/phpmyadmin/,` it gives me an error. The screen shot is as below

[image]

as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818358/phpmyadmin-default-password) article i have configured the `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;` but still it doesnt work.

It changes the screen as this tough
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: uhm, you can google for a password reset **at mysql** (phpmyadmin is using MySql login entry to give you access). And please note that phpmyadmin doesn't allow blank passwords.

Comment: refer this:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error code `#1045` is for wrong login, but `#2002` is cannot connect,  means, wrong host name in config file of phpMyAdmin.**

Check the config for `bind-address` - when set to `127.0.0.1` (default), you should be able to login (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']`) using `127.0.0.1` **or** `localhost`, **try both.**

phpMyAdmin recognizes `localhost` as host **and** local unix sockets.

If all fails, find out your real MySQL `root` password, which shouldn't be empty. Then try to login from console using `mysql -u root`. If it works, then there is a problem with the host.

You can turn off the controluser which is not necessary.

**Update:**

Your MySQL server is not running.

Look into `/var/log/syslog`, it should contain a reason or try to start it by:

```
service mysql start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Comment: i have commented out the statement you mentioned. still the same error

Comment: please check the picture i posted for mysql -u root

Comment: I mentioned several variables, ... dude. Is it possible that your mysql server is simply not running? Can you post the output of `ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: check please. config file as well

Comment: it's not a phpMyAdmin issue, your mysql server is not running

Comment: thanks. i figured out that mysql isnt actually installed:P it works now! thanks

Answer (score 0):

## **Cant log in to the host's phpmyadmin:**

if you're getting `#2002` Cannot log in to the MySQL server when logging in to phpmyadmin, try editing phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

***http://blog.ryantremaine.com/2011/03/2002-cannot-log-in-to-mysql-server.html***

***like this:***

1. *Right-click My Computer -> Manage -> Services*
2. *Choose "Services" under the "Services and Application" from right pane*
3. *Then search for the "Zend Development" Service.*
4. *When you find it, double click to start that service.*

***update:1***

> The problem was that the /etc/mysql/my.cnf was writable by another user than 'root'. So during the installation of mysql, the file was ignored and the installation didn't worked well.

```
chmod 644 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
aptitude remove mysql-server
aptitude install mysql-server
aptitude install mysql-common
```

Comment: OP is using Ubuntu, not Windows, nor did he mention Zend Server.