# phpmyadmin - What is the default user and password

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm following a guide online on Google Cloud Messenger. I got to this php file:

```
<?php

// Database config variables
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "xxxxxxxxx");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "xxxxxxx");
define("DB_DATABASE", "gcm");

// Google Cloud Messaging API Key
// Place your Google API Key
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyA81yS1VSj1WZXY_T"); 

?>
```

What should I fill in for DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD? What are the defaults?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default login password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818358/default-login-password)

Comment: `localhost` - host, `root` - username , and no password

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is a MySQL **client**, not a server. It doesn't have any kind of password of its own. Are you asking what your Google Cloud Messenger password is?

Comment: If it's your installation of SQL you should have specified a password at install. If your not on your own installation, then ask for SQL administrator to set you up a user.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (connect as root)

```
<?php

// Database config variables
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "gcm");

// Google Cloud Messaging API Key
// Place your Google API Key
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyA81yS1VSj1WZXY_T"); 

?>
```