# phpMyAdmin logging me as a new "cpses_****@localhost" user every time. How can I force it to be "myuser@localhost"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a VPS account running WHM/cPanel, so it's got phpMyAdmin installed by default.  If I log in through WHM, I am "root@localhost" so thankfully that works.

Back when I started working on a particular domain, I could get to phpMyAdmin through that domain's cPanel and it would log me in as (domain_login)@localhost, so those Procedures, for example, have the definer set as (domain_login)@localhost.

Recently, though, if I log in via the domain's cPanel pages, the user is always "cpses_******@localhost" where ***** is some psuedo-random string (associated with the user session, I would guess).  **The problem is** that "cpses_****@localhost" doesn't have access to anything created by anything else, including (domain_login)@localhost or any of the other "cpses_****@localhost" users that were created.  **I can't edit, or even *read*, anything that was created in the past!**

How do I force phpMyAdmin to login as the domain_login user again??

Comment: I tried setting the auth_type from "cpanel" (yes, that's what it was) to "cookie" and "http" both.  While I could log in as the correct user, it would instantly "timeout" and I was unable to navigate within phpMyAdmin (even after deleting cookies, trying new browser, etc).

Answer (score 1):

My `root` password and my domain's password were recently changed to be the same.  (Shush, you!)  As such, when I logged into cPanel, it showed me the warning that I was logged as a reseller / root account.  I ignored it.

What I didn't know is that while logged into cPanel as reseller / root, when going to phpMyAdmit, it gives you access of a TEMPORARY USER, specifically cpses_xxxxxx@localhost.

Changing my root password to something different fixed the whole issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post on StackExchange: [Default login password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818358/default-login-password)

Sorry I don't have more time to be more precise!
Stephen

Comment: I can log in fine.  My domain_login and password gets me into phpMyAdmin.  The problem is the user is "cpses_***@localhost" instead of "domain_login@localhost"