# What are the username and password for phpmyadmin login form as I have just set up phpmyadmin on the server using FTP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I uploaded phpmyadmin and set it up and now it's working but it prompts for username and password as I set auth type to cookies. Do I require username and password of my SQL on server? I don't have much idea about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

They should the the credentials on the database.  If you have a MYSQL user `bob` with a password of `password`, simply use that.

Also see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818385/1355043

Comment: How can I make DB when I don;t have access to my SQL or phpmyadmin?