# How to set username and password for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`, it shows like this:

[image]

But how to set the username and password.

I have tried in the terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but it says:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

If I type username: root and password: [blank]

It shows me:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing user: root; password: leave blank? More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5818385/5153030

Comment: Hi @alljamin, I tried leave blank but when I click go button, it has no thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to search for a file called: **config.inc.php** in your system and open it with an editor of your choice.

Then either search for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` and set it to True: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;` (**Attention:** use that only if you want to login without a password)

or if you want to login with a password(**recommended**) locate:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` and set your password like so:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';
```

Comment: Hi @coder, I open config.inc.php file, but I don't see `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` this line.

Comment: Hi @coder, I only see config.sample.inc.php, I don't see config.inc.php, but in config.sample.inc.php, I see this `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']`. But when I set to true, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Khuong, config.sample.inc.php is just a minimal configuration file, and in your case if config.inc.php file is missing your will have to create one manually. To do that take a look at here: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file

Comment: @Khuong, Also check if there is a file config.default.php and try to modify that file instead, as config.inc.php is not always required.

Comment: So I should delete config.sample.inc.php and create new config.inc.php?

Comment: Hi @coder, I don't see config.default.php, maybe I need to redownload phpmyadmin again.

Comment: @Khuong, that is recommended as a clear installation may save you from custom fixing steps. Also consider some manuals on the internet about the setup so you won't have any problems in the configuration!