# How to change the password for phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

Recently I installed the Bitnami Wordpress canned deployment on Google Cloud Platform.

I can view the phpMyAdmin instance at a local address (http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin/) but I cannot determine the username and password to log into the database cluster. I have tried the username specified in Deployment Manager, but the temporary password is not working. When I attempt to login, I receive the following error:

> `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I have tried to use various common passwords, such as root/root, with no success. If we assume the password is lost, how I can I figure out the password, recover it, or change it by using an SSH shell to the hosting compute instance?

Comment: you should check bitbami docs https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/redmine/operating/find_credentials_db/

Comment: Thank you for replying, but i have checked this and  i got the default user and password, but this not working. regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh it's opened now, the user was (**root**) which it's not mentioned anywhere when i created the instance, the password is the one which generated by Bitnami when the instance is created on the bitnami platform lunchpad website.

the password is used for 2 users :

- username: user
- username : root  (hidden) for new users who are decided to try cloud servers is not easy to figure this username and which password must use.

thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting password by supporting team if possible try

Comment: is these commands must run on SSH, how i suppose go to that folder config.inc.php.

Comment: Sorry dear by mistake i think you are using locally

Comment: how i shall ask support if im using Google Cloud platform, maybe i must re-install using Bitnami platform account

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems related to phpmyadmin. I found [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818358/default-login-password) where they stated:

> This is asking for your MySQL username and password.
>
> You should enter these details, which will default to "root" and ""
>   (i.e.: nothing) if you've not specified a password.

**UPDATE**

Have you tried to create a new user or change the password? Check this guide on [how to do it](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users).

Comment: thank you, but the problem how i can access to the files which it is in the explanation, what is the command, i have tried first command and its asking me a password which i don't know

Comment: Update the post using "edit" with all the sparsed information in the two answers and comments, please, because I do not understand anymore what are you referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

As our guide mentions, once you create the SSH tunnel to access phpMyAdmin, you need to use the user 'root' and the password we configure at boot time (it's the same password we configure in the application). More information in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/components/phpmyadmin/