# How to solve the mysqldump Got error: 1044: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_name'" when selecting the database

Tags: mysql, go, phpmyadmin

I use mysqldump command to dump the some information from the sql tables. To do this I read about mysqldump. Then for a test I made a direct command which will run able in the terminal shell. That command were successfully produces the result which I needed. Then after that I have to implemented the command in my application code. My application is in the golang. Using `exec.Command()` I will able to run that command. But there is a run time error while the command will executed. The error I'm facing in terminal is:

> exit status 2: mysqldump: Got error: 1044: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_name'" when selecting the database

Command which I used:

direct command which produce success result
`sudo mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 --no-create-info db_name table_name --where='id=1121' > /path/of/file/php1_dump.sql`

code I'm using in golang:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 --no-create-info db_name table_name --where='id=1121' > /home/iron/go/php1_dump.sql")
var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr

err := cmd.Run() // give the above error I mentioned

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    fmt.Println("errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr", err) // exit status 2
}
fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
```

I also tried the below commands:

`sudo mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p --no-create-info bk_admin wp_merchants --where='id=1121' > /home/iron/go/php1_dump.sql`

The above command ask to enter the password. But I didn't setup any password of phpmysqladmin:

[image: User accounts overview page: all accounts have Password: No]

Please tell me that where I'm doing this wrong?

Comment: There will be a password. Do you have an application that uses this database successfully? You can probably find a password, though maybe not the root password, in that app's config. Worst case you can stop mysql and restart it `--skip-grant-tables` then change the password to something you do know.

Comment: @rup But I didn't setup any password on mysql. So what password I would have to change

Comment: It might either be [empty (just hit return) or 'password'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818385/243245). But whether you know it or not [you can follow these steps to change it](https://askubuntu.com/a/766908/24979).

Comment: @rup I have checked in user account see in the given screen shot: https://nimb.ws/suN974   there is no password in the user account

Comment: Sorry, I don't know my mysql behaves with no passwords set. I've put your screenshot in the question so hopefully someone else will recognise what's happening here.

Comment: @rup okay thankyou for the links. Anyone other will give me the solution for this?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced this same problem. I think you will have to make a new user in your `PHPMyAdmin -> users_account` with a valid `username` and `password`. Also, check all the privileges. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is prompting you to specify a password because you asked it to.

First skip *-p* in your command.

Use

> --skip-password

To explicitly specify that there is no password and that mysqldump should not prompt for one.